# How to concatenate tensor to another list of tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor of shape "torch.Size([2, 2, 3])" and another tensor of shape "`torch.Size([2, 1, 3])`". I want a concatenated tensor of shape "`torch.Size([2, 2, 6])`".

 For example :

```
a=torch.tensor([[[2,3,5],[12,13,15]],[[20,30,50],[120,130,150]]])
b=torch.tensor([[[99,99,99]],[[999,999,999]]])
```

I want the output as : `[[[99,99,99,2,3,5],[99,99,99,12,13,15]],[[999,999,999,20,30,50],[999,999,999,120,130,150]]]`

I have written a O(n2) solution using two for loops but,
This is taking a lot of time with millions of calculation, Does anyone help me in doing this efficiently ?? May be some matrix calculation trick for tensors ??

Comment: Thanks @Gilseung Ahn for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exactly match the example you have provided:

`c = torch.cat([b.repeat([1,a.shape[1]//b.shape[1],1]),a],2)`

The reasoning behind this is that the concatenate operation in pytorch (and numpy and other libraries) will complain if the dimensions of the two tensors in the non-specified axes (in this case 0 and 1) do not match. Therefore, you have to repeat the tensor along the non-matching axis (the first axis, therefore the second element of the repeat list) in order to make the dimensions align. *Note that the solution here will only work if the middle dimension of a is evenly divisible by the middle dimension of b.*

In newer versions of pytorch, this can also be done using the `torch.tile()` function.

Comment: Thanks @jhso for this solution. It worked well and even I tried with torch.expand() with the same logic of repeating. Both worked well.